# masonry images not stacking vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, masonry

I'm trying implement the masonry with random images but it is not stacking vertically. The second row of images is not stacking. I followed the instructions but it's not clear. I added the images, javascript, and stylesheet.

Here is my **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require masonry/masonry
//= require masonry/jquery.event-drag
//= require masonry/jquery.imagesloaded.min
//= require masonry/jquery.infinitescroll.min
//= require masonry/modernizr-transitions
//= require masonry/box-maker
//= require masonry/jquery.loremimages.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require custom
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css**

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require masonry/basic
 *= require masonry/centered
 *= require masonry/fluid
 *= require masonry/gutters
 *= require masonry/infinitescroll
 *= require masonry/right-to-left
 *= require masonry/transitions
 */
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="masonry-container" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix">

      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/236x190">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/236x177">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/236x342">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/236x156">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/236x182">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/236x341">
      </div>

      <div class="box col1">
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box col2">
        <p>
          <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/nemoorange/3319714470/" title="Whitlow's on Wilson by nemoorange, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3008/3319714470_c05a5cb5a8_m.jpg" alt="Whitlow's on Wilson" /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In order to help we'll need to see your actual final CSS, if you can duplicate the issue in a JSFiddle that would also be helpful.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/wcw0fgk7/. My goal is have similar layout as Pinterest which has a 236 x PPP format for images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#masonry-container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.box'
  });
});
</script>
```

What I understand is that the images have to load first, then fire the masonry script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initialising the Masonary script? Here is an example with the initialisation taking place in the JavaScript area:

https://jsfiddle.net/4zngmzzd/

I used the plain JavaScript initialisation but there is also a jQuery version:

```
//Plain JavaScript
var elem = document.getElementById('masonry-container');
var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
  itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

The Masonary homepage contains further info on initialisation: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Did you initialise the script or is it something else?

(jQuery version: https://jsfiddle.net/0a73a1qd/)

Comment: I added the JS code but now in chrome inspect element, there is an error. Bad masonry element: null

Comment: @user1552815 - Make sure that you're *not* including a `#` in `document.getElementById('masonry-container');`. It's just `masonry-container`, not `#masonry-container`. Was that the issue?

Comment: `<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#masonry-container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.box'
      });
    });
  </script>` Somehow using document.ready didn't work. The images were overlapping.

Comment: @user1552815 - Is this what you typed that doesn't work?

Comment: I did but I convert to the jQuery way.

Comment: @user1552815 - You've started the script incorrectly. Change it to match my new example: https://jsfiddle.net/0a73a1qd/

Comment: @user1552815 - Did you copy my example. The `$(window).load` part of your code is incorrect. Copy what I wrote and it should work, `$(document).ready`. Let me know how it goes.